# How to fetch HTTP headers using JAX-RS?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I have the following URL for calling a web service

```
http://localhost:8080/mdnd_myshelfService_V1.0/myshelf/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails?username=85010352:password=cHdfODUwMTAzNTIk
```

Along with this i need to send username and password from particular device as to verify the device based on hardcoded username and password in the form of header field.

```
@GET
@Path("/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Hospital getAllHospitalData(@QueryParam("username") String userId) {
    log.error("in getAllHospitalData.. " + userId + " | " );
    }
```

What should i do to get the header fields: `MYSHELF_IPHONEUser_QA` and `MYSHELF_IPHONEUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not calling the web service properly because if you want to pass a query string for `username` and `password`, use the `&` operator to list them after the  `?`.

```
http://localhost:8080/...?username=85010352&password=cHdfODUwMTAzNTIk
```

Comment: I would post this as a comment since it does not answer the question but you are asking for clarification.

Comment: @Tichodroma thats all right the url format cannot be changed as it is not upto us we are getting this request from server only and we dnt have access to change.Thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JAX-RS, you can access HTTP headers using [`@HeaderParam`](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html):

```
@GET
@Path("/authenticateUserAndGetHospitalDetails")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Hospital getAllHospitalData(
  @QueryParam("username") String userId,
  @HeaderParam("MYSHELF_IPHONEUser_QA") String userQaHeader,
  @HeaderParam("MYSHELF_IPHONEUser") String userHeader) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thnx a lot for the answer